# How do I achieve this particularly chart type in Python using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, charts, scatter-plot

I am using Python 3 and Jupyter Notebook for my Python projects.

I came across the chart mentioned in the link below:

[Matplotlib Chart](http://styleguide.strawlab.org/_images/bad_good.png)

I want to create something similar with my data but I am having a hard time finding the codes to do so. Is this chart a scatterplot, even if it has categorical values on the x-axis? Or should I use another chart type to achieve what I am after?

My current scatterplot codes look like this:

```
x = mySelectedData['Leisure Per GN']
y = mySelectedData['Spa Per GN']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
colors = 'blue'
size = 250 #(10 + np.random.rand(num_points) * 10) ** 2  
ax.scatter(x, y, s=size, c=colors, alpha=0.5)  
fig.suptitle('CY 2015 - CY 2016:Leisure Per Gn versus Spa Per Gn')
```

Above codes works fine as both x an y are numerical values. I have changed the codes to the following:

```
x = mySelectedData['Market']
y = mySelectedData['Leisure Per GN']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
colors = 'green'
size = 250 #(10 + np.random.rand(num_points) * 10) ** 2  
ax.scatter(x, y, s=size, c=colors, alpha=0.5)  
fig.suptitle('Leisure Per Gn: UK v/s Germany (CY 2016 -CY 2017)')
```

When running these lines of code, Python throws the following error message:

```
ValueError: First argument must be a sequence
```

I guess it has to do with the fact that 'Market' is a categorical data.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I would try assigning arbitrary numerical values to your categorical data, just to get the spacing the way you want it, and then use something like this to set your labels:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as politicker

#Add x ticks at specified intervals
x_labels = ["foo", "bar"]
label_locations = [0, 1, 2, 3] #chosen x locations   

loc = plticker.FixedLocator()
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
plt.xticks(x_labels, label_locations)
```

That way, you're still  plotting your categorical data, but Matplotlib thinks you're plotting numerical data.

Comment: Thanks. I will give your solution a try. However, I am bit confused at the line X_labels = ["foo", "bar"]. If I put this in my context, I guess it would read as follows: X_labels = mySelectedData['Market']; is that correct?
Also, shouldn't the line where we do the "import matplotlib.ticker as politicker" read as "import matplotlib.ticker as plticker" since you are later using "loc = plticker.FixedLocator()" ?